# Xpath for Hyperlink

Tags: html, dom, xpath, hyperlink

I need relative Xpath for below line

```
"<a name="newvol_link" title="New Volunteer Signup" id="newvol_link" onclick="doAction('NEW_VOL_LINK', event);;return false" href="javascript:void(0)">"
```

One way is find it by `findElement(By.linkText(“New Volunteer Signup”));`
But I want proper Xpath for this expression.

Addded DOM path

```
<div class="information">                                           
    <div align="center">                                 
        <table width="90%" border="0">                       
            <tbody>                               
                <tr align="left" vAlign="top">      
                    <td width="40%">         
                        <b>              
                            <br/>    
                            <br/>      
                            <br/>     
                            <br/>    
                                <a name="newvol_link" title="New Volunteer Signup" id="newvol_link" onclick="doAction('NEW_VOL_LINK', event);;return false" href="javascript:void(0)">
```

Comment: The xpath is the path in the DOM to that element......  For a proper xpath expression you need to know where exactly in the DOM that the element exists.  Which means all parent elements are needed.

Comment: Updated the post with DOM path

Comment: There are many possible XPath location paths for any given node; none of them is inherently "more proper" than the others. You should be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//a[@title="New Volunteer Signup"]
```

or, a bit more specific

```
//a[@id="newvol_link" and @title="New Volunteer Signup"]
```

(`//a[@id="newvol_link"]` should be sufficient but HTML permits multiple elements sharing the same `id` attribute so beware)

or, with some parent elements

```
//div[@class="information"]//table//tr/td//a[@id="newvol_link" and @title="New Volunteer Signup"]
```

Comment: <a class="active" href="javascript:goToRecruiter('VolunteerRegistration')"> Can you tell me Xpath for this expression as well? Or any documentation link where I can learn more about Xpath?

Comment: As comments on the question said, it always depends on document context what would make a good XPath expression for an element. For your element in previous comment, you could test for attribute value equality, i.e. `//a[@href="javascript:goToRecruiter('VolunteerRegistration')"]`, or  `//a[contains(@href, "goToRecruiter('VolunteerRegistration')")]` to test part of the attribute value. As for example, http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev gives some common patterns, or http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp